# Python - AttributeError with hashlib: no such attribute: "openssl_md_meth_names"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know why this is happening, but after some crazy recovery from installing python from source, when anything imports hashlib, it comes up with something like this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.log import logger
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip import backwardcompat
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/backwardcompat/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from urllib2 import URLError, HTTPError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 93, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you still have the wrong hashlib (the one without openssl_md_meth_names) hanging around. It is being imported instead of the proper one.

Do this as a root:

```
# cd /
# find . | grep hashlib
```

Then remove (ok, rename ;-) ) any hashlib files not in /usr/lib/python2.7

Comment: OK, I just needed to fix a single line: `except ImportError:` to `except:`

Answer (score 2):

My python was saved by removing file 
`./usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

I have no idea where did it come from, but removing it made importing hashlib and using pip working again